# DNS Resolver result from multiple nameservers

Tags: perl, dns

I am passing two name servers to the [`Net::DNS::Resolver`](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aDNS%3a%3aResolver) constructor but I am getting only one result back.

How should I change the code to receive result from all the name servers?

```
sub resolve_dns()
{
    my $dns = $_[0];
    my $res   = Net::DNS::Resolver->new(

                nameservers => [qw(24.116.197.232 114.130.11.67 )],
                recurse     => 0,
                debug       => 1,
                tcp_timeout => 3
                );
    my $query = $res->search($dns);

    if ($query) {
        foreach my $rr ($query->answer) {
            next unless $rr->type eq "A";
            print $rr->address, "\n";
        }
    } else {
        warn "query failed: ", $res->errorstring, "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume the DNS servers after the first are there for fallback purposes and only a single reply will ever be returned.

The best way seems to be to manipulate the `Net::DNS::Resolver` server list and explicitly make a request to each of them.

This example code demonstrates the principle

```
sub resolve_dns {

  my $address = shift;

  my $res = Net::DNS::Resolver->new
    recurse     => 0,
    debug       => 1,
    tcp_timeout => 3,
  );

  for my $ns (qw( 24.116.197.232  114.130.11.67 )) {

    $res->nameservers($ns);

    my $reply = $res->send($address);

    if ($reply) {
      my @type_a = grep $_->type eq 'A', $reply->answer;
      print $_->address, "\n" for @type_a;
    }
    else {
      warn sprintf "Query to %s failed: %s\n", $ns, $res->errorstring;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Whenever I give `$res->nameservers($ns)` statement, code is hung and no print statements are working. When I comment that line, everything is working.

Comment: The code will hang if you are using an invalid DNS server address. Check the value of `$ns` that you are passing to the `nameservers` method. Note also that you must pass a bare string for the address, not an anonymous array as you do for the constructor. Do they have leading or trailing whitespace perhaps? Those addresses don't work for me but I imagine they are on a private network.